# Multiple Dynamic SEO/shortened URLs in PHP

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a PHP system containing user-generated pages, arranged in a complex and non-uniform hierarchy. Pages are created by users, and some pages have sub-pages etc.

I have been asked to add a shortened-url system. So any page, at any point in the hierarchy, can be accessed via **domain.com/XXXX** where XXXX can be anything - we are not interested in SEO here, the reasoning behind this is its a very social-media driven project, and we would like our users to be able to tweet/other the url of any page they like.

I expect something like; we start on AAAA and head towards ZZZZ as each page is created. Each of these slugs would be stored in the database alongside the actual url eg **domain.com/projects.php?p=32**

I know mod-rewrite enough to convert **domain.com/XXXX** into **domain.com/index.php?slug=XXXX**, but where to go from there leaves me a little stumped. index.php can do the database lookup and header() the user to the actual url, but the slug-url needs to stay in the address bar.

Would using an iframe in index.php be a terrible idea?

I hope thats clear, thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

If you used the `[R=301]` directive at the end of an .htaccess rewrite rule, it will act as a redirect. Meaning if you go to **domain.com/XXXX** it will show **domain.com/index.php?slug=XXXX** in the address bar. Is that the behavior you're trying to accomplish?

Also, I wouldn't use a `header()`, I'd make your index page be the processing page. Either that, or use an `include()` method instead.

Comment: I *think* the OP wants to keep the URL as domain.com/XXXX but to show the destination page, which could be something like domain.com/pages/username/xxx.php

Answer (score 0):

I think using an iframe is a terrible idea, and will lead to a brittle site.

Is there any reason why `index.php` can't act as a front controller, so instead of redirecting it just shows the page? You should just be able to `include` the page.

---

Alternatively, could you not rewrite `domain.com/XXXX` to `domain.com/projects.php?slug=XXXX`, and do a slug->p conversion at the top of `projects.php`? Then the conversion would just need to record slugs and page ids, rather than slugs and full URLs.

Comment: I read somewhere that you cannot include with GET vars. I suppose I could just bring variables into scope and then include. Each page also needs a conversation thread, i might have to rethink this a whole lot. Its starting to look like wordpress.

Comment: Good point. I think it makes more sense to redirect to the new URL rather than keeping the slug anyway. That's what people are more used to. e.g. follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6470359/49376